# Printing integers into a character array c++

Tags: arrays

I need help printing calculations output by a loop, in reverse order. I would like the program to be able to handle large values if desired, so I decided to use a character array. Unfortunately I don't really know how to do this. I kind of put something together that gives me answers with smaller values, but turns into gobbledie gook with larger values. I'm sure it's misunderstanding of how to use and display arrays. I may need to convert the integers to characters first, but I don't know how to do that either. Any help would be appreciated! The code for the array is down at the bottom in the convert_bases() function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void convert_2_decimal(int, int, int&);
void convert_base(int, int);

const int ARRAY_SIZE = 100;

int main()
{
    int     base1,          // Base of original number
            base2,          // Base of converted number
            number,         // Original number
            decimal;        // Number converted to decimal

    cout << "Please enter the base of your number (between [2-10]):"   << endl;
    cin  >> base1;

    cout << "Please enter your number:" << endl;
    cin  >> number;

    cout << "Please enter the base (between [2-10])"    << endl
         << "You would like your number converted to"   << endl;
    cin  >> base2;

    // splits up number into "decimal" places (ones, 
    // tens, hundreds, etc) and converts to decimal
    convert_2_decimal(number, base1, decimal);

    // Converts to base specified by user, saves to string
    convert_base(base2, decimal);


    return 0;   
}
void convert_2_decimal(int user_number, int user_base, int &converted_2_decimal)
{
    int remainder,  // result of mod
        count;      // Counts which "decimal" place is being found

    count = 0;
    converted_2_decimal = 0;
    while (user_number > 0)
    {
        remainder = user_number % 10;

        // Subtracts remainder and divides by ten to get 
        // number for next  "decimal" place
        user_number = (user_number - remainder) / 10; 

        // Keeps total to convert to decimal
        converted_2_decimal += (remainder * pow(user_base, count++));
    }
    cout <<endl << converted_2_decimal << endl;   // test for correct output
}


void convert_base(int new_base, int number)
{
    int digit,          // Number converted into new base
        count;          // counts number of loop iterations

    string digits[ARRAY_SIZE];  // String of digits to print converted number


    while (number > 0)
    {
        digit = number % new_base;
        number /= new_base;

        digits[count++] = digit;  // saves each digit to string
    }

    for(count; count > 0; count--)
    {
        cout << digits[count] << endl;  
    }   
}
```

Comment: Also forgot to mention it prints a bunch of blank space after the number, instead of just the digits I want.

Comment: What programming language is this? Is it C++? Please tag your question with the language in use. To update your question, click on the **"[edit]"** link under the post. Thank you.